# how to copy already opened file?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a handle to a file, it is opened.

```
HANDLE h = ::CreateFile(...)
```

I would like to copy this file. How to do that? I would like to do something like this:

```
CopyFile(h, "new_file.dat");
```

I know there is `CopyFile(fileName, newFileName)` function, but it seems that I would have to close my handle before using this calling this function. Is there another way of doing the copy?

Comment: It might be enough to ensure that the source file has been fully flushed to disk. Then just use the filename you used in your `CreateFile` call.

Comment: You'd only have an issue if your CreateFile call was not opened with any kind of sharing, which you haven't shared with us.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Right! I have no sharing enabled, and when I put FILE_SHARE_READ it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are working in windows. The problem is that in windows when you open a file it by default gets blocked for other opens (Copy also opens the file). As I know CreateFile has a flag that allows to open file in shared mode. That flag by definition should solve your problem.